# Some versions of "Sorry"

Tags: phrase-usage

Are all versions of "Sorry" idiomatic and interchangeable? I'm really surprised about some versions of apologizing. Which phrases can be used in formal speaking?

> Sorry, my mistake.
>
> I'm sorry, my mistake.
>
> I'm very sorry, my mistake.
>
> Sorry for my mistake.
>
> Terribly sorry, my mistake.
>
> Terribly sorry for my mistake.
>
> I'm terribly sorry for my mistake.
>
> I'm really sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Yes, you are likely to hear all of them, and a great many more!

Comment: In a formal setting your longer apologies might be preferred. "Sorry, my mistake" is a bit casual maybe. Two short sentences - "I apologise. I've made a mistake" or "I'm so sorry. I've slipped up" - might be more appropriate. (In the UK at least.)